# Trouble getting zip_utils to work with gzip files

Tags: c++, zip, gzip, zlib

I am using zip_utils.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-Clean-Elegant-Simple-Cplusplus-Win

I got it to work with zip files but I am unable to deflate any .gz (gzip) files. The documentation (see above) seems to indicate it should work. Here's the code I am using:

```
HZIP hz = OpenZip(sourcePath.c_str(), 0);
SetUnzipBaseDir(hz, dir.c_str());
ZIPENTRY ze; GetZipItem(hz, -1, &ze); int numitems = ze.index; // -1 gives overall information about the zipfile

for (int zi = 0; zi < numitems; zi++)
{
    ZIPENTRY ze; GetZipItem(hz, zi, &ze); // fetch individual details
    UnzipItem(hz, zi, ze.name);         // e.g. the item's name.
    //UnzipItem(hz, zi, destPath.c_str());         
}
CloseZip(hz);
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Any error code?

Comment: No error codes generated.  Output file is empty.

Comment: Did you check? All of those "zip" functions return their status.

Comment: Just ran a test on all zip functions. with a zip file, all functions returned zero. 

However, with a gz file, openzip returned, 131: "an attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file"

Comment: I know nothing about that library, was just pointing out that you always need to check the return code from any API. Also, that library was not touched in over 15 years; aren't there any more up-to-date (and maintained) zip libraries? (Don't answer that; it was a rhetorical question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no indication that this library will process gzip files.

Comment: from the above page, "This code is based on gzip 1.1.4"

Comment: I think they meant that it is based on gzip but as you say, this doesn't mean it actually can deflate a gzip. I am marking your answer as the best. 

It also says in the source code for "unzip.cpp": "The library also supports reading and writing files in gzip (.gz) format
//  with an interface similar to that of stdio." 

but you are right, it doesn't say, "this library" it says, "the library". my mistake

Comment: It uses code from gzip only for the core compression and decompression of deflate data. It does not process the gzip format.